# laravel project structure and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, file, laravel, project-structure

I've installed new laravel project on a local server and encountered problem that the simple demo routes with "Hello" view was not working, returning 404 error. After I copy/pasted .htaccess file from another project, routes started to work, but could not access public folder with css styles. How are files like routes.php or public folder connected/called? It is the responsibility of .htacces file?

--

What if hosting server doesnt support .htaccess? Can laravel app run on such servers?

Comment: No the .htaccess simply routes all the urls to the index.php file which basically starts the application (and later includes the routes.php) So without the .htaccess when you enter `/hello` it the server is searching for a subdirectory with the name hello

Comment: Then what exactly should be in .htaccess file to route all urls to index.php

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)'s the one that comes with a default installation

Comment: Sometimes this kind of error for copy/pasted not working htaccess, when used FTP to send files, is related to the transmission of the file. Yous need to use text mode and not binary. And ftp softwares don't always know .htacces text files...

Comment: Does it mean that hosting server must provide Mod_rewrite mode?